# Conversion of Data Type in column of migration table

Tags: ruby, database, migration

Suppose that I have a table Attendances (id(integer), login_date(date), login_time(time),logout_time (time)). Now I have to change the data type of logout_time from time to datetime. So how it can be possible in Migration ? Because i Tried this statement in new migration.

change_column(attendances, logout_time, time, datetime)

Please suggest me ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic question.
Should try this

```
change_column :attendances, :logout_time, :datetime
```